# how to dynamically create an output file for psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a SQL script that will be used to make changes in the database. For audit and traceability reasons, I want the script to generate an output file name based on the DBNAME and timestamp.

```
db_test=> select 'script_output-' || :'DBNAME' || '-' ||
 to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd-HH24MISS') || '.txt' as spoolfile;
                 spoolfile
--------------------------------------------
 script_output-db_test-20190718-163936.txt
```

However, when I try to assign the query result to the \out operator I get the following

```
db_test=> \out select 'script_output-' || :'DBNAME' || '-' || to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd-HH24MISS') || '.txt'
\out: extra argument "script_output-" ignored
\out: extra argument "||" ignored
\out: extra argument ":'DBNAME'" ignored
\out: extra argument "||" ignored
\out: extra argument "-" ignored
\out: extra argument "||" ignored
\out: extra argument "to_char(now(),yyyymmdd-HH24MISS)" ignored
\out: extra argument "||" ignored
\out: extra argument ".txt" ignored
```

The output file actually created was named select

```
SDV184022L:~ myuser$ ls -la Downloads/DB-Install/sele*
-rw-r--r--  1 myuser  myuser     0B Jul 18 11:42 Downloads/DB-Install/select
```

Based on these results and lots of searching, I'm going to assume this is not possible so does anyone have an alternative way to accomplish generating a dynamic filename for the output directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Results generated by a query can be transfered to auto-instantiated variables in psql with `\gset`. The names of the variables are the names of the columns. Try

```
db_test=> select 'script_output-' || :'DBNAME' || '-' ||
 to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd-HH24MISS') || '.txt' as spoolfile
 \gset
```

Then you can do

```
db_test=> \out :spoolfile
```

Be aware that the variable is handled with a "macro" kind of expansion. So if the value of `:spoolfile` happened to contain spaces or backslashes, psql would interpret them as if they had been input on the command line.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, that is exactly what I was looking for. Will add this to my SQL template file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `psql` variable to store the result of the query by running a `psql` command within it.

```
knayak=# \set v_spoolfile `psql -A -t -c "select 'script_output-' ||  current_database() || '-' ||to_char(now(),'yyyymmdd-HH24MISS') || '.txt' as spoolfile" yourdbname`
knayak=# \echo :v_spoolfile
script_output-knayak-20190718-225537.txt
knayak=# \out :v_spoolfile
```